# .slidetoggle() specific item's after click on their icon

Tags: jquery, toggle, slidetoggle, box

i want to create a box to can show my server ip on that

for this i create this:

```
codepen.io/AlirezaBehnamnik/pen/xEVpBL
```

i want when click on down icon in "Asia Game Public #1" box , just show ip of this box not other box

thanks

Comment: Can you check this? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ozxqOL

Comment: didn't work! :(

Comment: I forgot to save that after the changes.. I have updated it.. can you check now?

Comment: thats it, thank you so much , just one more question , can you change it to whene one box is open and i click in other box , other box was close :-? sry for bad english xD

Comment: Check now and Please accept the answer if it works for you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a unique class/id to show/hide the specific div. 
check the updated link :

```
//codepen.io/anon/pen/ozxqOL
```