# jQuery Slidetoggle - show/hide sub menu on one box only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a page where I have showing multiple boxes, and each box have three vertical dots on top right corner, when you click on those three dots it will open sub menu, for which I have used `slidetoggle` and what I wanted is when user click on the dots from one box it should show at once place only but right now its showing on all boxes, the `jQuery` I have written is not working as expected.

**Here is the [JSfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/wo1b58wj/)**

For slide toggle I have the following JQuery:

```
$('.popout_info > a').click(function () {
  $(".popout_info").next().slideToggle(200);
});
```

Can anyone please suggest how to handle this, if I assign ID to each `DIV` then in this case the boxes are going to be in unlimited numbers, may be something which can be handled dynamically?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *`$(this).parent(".popout_info").next().slideToggle(200);`* will do the trick.

Comment: I tried the above code but didn't worked...

Comment: check this , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39505518/slidetoggle-specific-items-after-click-on-their-icon

Comment: thats what I dont want since boxes are going to be unlimited, if something which can do dynamically instead of having different IDs or classes

Comment: check this [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/wo1b58wj/4) if thats what you want.

Comment: yes, that worked, please post it as a answer so I could accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change your *jQuery* function to achieve that as:

### jQuery

```
$('.popout_info > a').click(function() {
  $('.popout_list').slideUp(200);
  var nextPopup = $(this).parent(".popout_info").siblings('.popout_list');
  if (!($(nextPopup).is(':visible'))) {
    $(nextPopup).slideToggle(200);
  }
});
```

Here's your updated <kbd>[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/wo1b58wj/6)</kbd>

> I have made some amendments to hide any other open popup if one popup opens to disallow redundancy.

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting every popup window. Try using :

```
$('.popout_list').slideUp(200);
$(this).closest('.doctor_wrapper').find('.popout_list').slideToggle(400);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to achieve this.

JS

```
$('.popout_info > a').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".popout_info").next().slideToggle(200);
  });
```

Or try this link 
https://jsfiddle.net/wo1b58wj/7/

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
$('.popout_info > a').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().next().slideToggle(200);
  });
```

and it worked for me.

Side note: it's hard to click on those three dots because the box resize on mouse enter/leave